# FindBugs filters: regex doesn't work in Class element

Tags: java, findbugs

I'm trying to configure FindBugs to ignore missing equals methods for data object classes (name ends with DO suffix).
The [documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html) says that this should work:

```
  <Match>
    <Class name=".*DO" />
    <Bug pattern="EQ_DOESNT_OVERRIDE_EQUALS" />
  </Match>
```

However it doesn't and I'm starting to doubt that regex is supported for Class/@name.
Interesting thing is that this actually works:

```
  <Match classregex=".*DO">
    <Bug pattern="EQ_DOESNT_OVERRIDE_EQUALS" />
  </Match>
```

P.S.: I'm using FindBugs 2.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a tilde before regexs in FindBugs. So it should look more like this:

```
 <Match>
    <Class name="~.*DO" />
    <Bug pattern="EQ_DOESNT_OVERRIDE_EQUALS" />
 </Match>
```